# <select> box styling difference on safari and firefox?

Tags: css, select, cross-browser

I am trying to simply style my select box so the text is centre aligned. It works in Firefox but not in Safari or Chrome. When inspecting the element in Chrome it says the text is centred, however this is not the case. Can anybody see why it is not centred in Chrome and Safari?

http://georgewoolfe.com/yogurtline1.html

Answer (score 0):

It will not work. Your best best is to use a plugin. E.g select menu :http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/

That actually replaces the select with a span but retains select functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Well, styling  tag is really hard. You have to test different browsers and OS, and hardly you will reach an uniform result.

http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/

I suggest you to use some alternative component or js replacement that emulate selects behaviour, if you want to style it in an easier way.

http://cssglobe.com/custom-styling-of-the-select-elements/

Answer (score 0):

There's no totally cross browser way of centering the test of a `<select>` element using just css. Some browsers allow you to do it and some don't.

If you really have to have it centered then I would suggest that you look into using an alternative component like [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) or [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/).